# how to print requestBody in logcat

Tags: android, android-studio, request, okhttp

I am using `okhttp3` to image upload in multipart. I am sending parameters in `requestBody` but I do not understand how to print all parameters in `logcat`. Please help

```
requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("image_file_name", filename + ".jpg"+",", fileBody)
                .addFormDataPart("name", edtName.getText().toString())
                .addFormDataPart("type", "P")
                .addFormDataPart("password", edtPwd.getText().toString())
                .addFormDataPart("c_password", edtConfrmPwd.getText().toString())
                .addFormDataPart("cloud_token", "AND")
                .addFormDataPart("gender", "M")
                .addFormDataPart("postal_code", edtPostCode.getText().toString())
                .addFormDataPart("address", edtAddress.getText().toString())
                .addFormDataPart("image_encode_string", encodeImage)
                .addFormDataPart("fcm_id", "11212")
                .addFormDataPart("email", edtEmail.getText().toString())
                .addFormDataPart("phone", edtPhone.getText().toString())
                .build();

        Log.e("TAG", "requestBody: "+requestBody.toString());
```

here

```
 Log.e("TAG", "requestBody: "+requestBody.toString());
```

prints

> okhttp3.MultipartBody@84d3c7f

and does not print all parameters.

Comment: Override toString() of the `MultipartBody` or [use this method about how to list parts of MultipartBody](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/MultipartBody.html#parts--).

Comment: @Jay how? I do not understand

Answer (score 2):

for printing requestBody, you need to use Logging Interceptor by retrofit, which will print logs related to request in logcat.

change your retrofit object like this ->

```
private static final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                    .addInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY))
                    .readTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .writeTimeout(WRITE_TIMEOUT_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .connectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

and add logging interceptor inside your gradle ->

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.12.0'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @mishti, by doing this you don't even need to use log.e, as it prints all request details as OkHttp tag.

Comment: @where i should use it

Comment: when you are cteating Retrofit Object, just  add this .addInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)).